# Hyperion Essbase Script Means

Tags: hyperion, essbase

I have script essbase calc from hyperion
like this

> "ACTUAL" = ("ACTUAL" +
>   ("ACTUAL"->"Labor_Hours"->"NA_CE"->"NA_CC"->"NA_ENTITY" *
>   "ACTUAL"->"NA_PRODUCT"));

i have no idea what that code means,

because my cube result alwasy zero 0

Answer (score 1):

To answer that, you have to identify the values for each of the following:

1. `"ACTUAL"->"Labor_Hours"->"NA_CE"->"NA_CC"->"NA_ENTITY"`for each product
2. Multiplying for `"ACTUAL"->"NA_PRODUCT"` where we can assume in the FIX section you have the members `CE_1, CC_1, ENTITY_1` then look for the following
   `"ACTUAL"->"NA_PRODUCT"->CE_1->CC_1->ENTITY_1`
3. The product of 1*2 will be added to "Actual" where we can assume 
   `"ACTUAL"->CE_1->CC_1->ENTITY_1` for each product

In this case, for sure, what can make you get a ZERO is that for 1 or 2 there's a ZERO or #Missing in you data.